# Maven: site and install interchangable?

Tags: java, maven, maven-site-plugin

In Maven, does `mvn site install` essentially the same as `mvn install site`, or does the first one generate a site from the previous `install`?

To be more precise: Is `site` independent from `install` or does `site` include results that were generated from `install`?

Comment: Have you checked the Maven output log to see which Maven goals are executed and in which order?

Answer (score 0):

Maven executes the goals in the order you give it, so it will `site` the previous `install` then do the new `install`

Another simple exemple to prove it is to make a `mvn install clean` and you will see the result as all targets will be removed by the end of the build

Comment: I know that goals are executed in the given order, the question is: Are site and install independent of each other or does the order really matter?

Comment: The order really matter, obviously... and the goals are always independant

Comment: If the goals are independent, the order does _not_ matter. The question is: Does site use results of install?

Comment: @JFMeier no, site read the pom xml and those of the dependencies to generate its documentation.

Comment: The `site` [lifecycle](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-are-the-phases-of-the-maven-site-lifecycle.html) is as follow : pre-site/site/post-site/dite-deploy, so it does not use the results of install

Answer (score 0):

By design, plugin goals that can be used as part of site generation ( `site` lifecycle), will  either not require the execution of `default` lifecycle or they will trigger it automatically. Most of them are "reporting" goals.
e.g. when `javadoc` is added in `<reporting>` section, it will additionally trigger the `default` lifecycle, when the user executes `mvn site`.

So in general `install` does not need to be executed before `site`.
Possible exceptions can be:

- A reporting plugin expects some input that is generated on the default lifecycle, but it does not trigger that lifecycle. In that case you should trigger the default lifecycle manually.
- A custom operation involving copy or download of a site resource is attached to a default lifecycle phase. Again you should trigger the default lifecycle manually.

Example:

Let's say you want to include the `README.md` (located on the root of your project) to the site. You will need to copy it inside `src/site/markdown` before the site generation.
For this you can use `copy-resources` goal from `resources` plugin.

Then you need to specify an execution phase for `copy-resources`:

- Declaring `process-resources` as execution phase: then `mvn process-resources site` (or `mvn install site`) is required, and the opposite won't work.
- Declaring `pre-site` as execution phase (which is more correct): then `mvn site` will be enough (since pre-site is a phase of `site` lifecycle and will be executed anyway).